# NodeJS Mongoose mapping of data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a hire platform for cars. Now i used mongoose, setup my models and found out i can't populate a reference that's too deep.

I got 2 models: Cars and Types and Customers.
I'm trying to receive everything from my Customers like placed orders. 
The response i'm getting currently is the one below.

```
"slug": "myslug",
"note": "",
"isReturned": false,
"includedKM": "0",
"price": "0",
"car": {
  "type": "_id"
}
```

I got the car to populate but i can't seem to get the type to populate. I tried things like `.populate('car.type')` but with no result. I looked this up and apparently it's too deep to populate so i came up with a solution to bypass this.

```
const customer = req.customer;

Order.find({'customer': customer.slug}).populate('car').then(function(orders){

        Car.find(orders).populate('type').then(function(types){
            return res.json(types);
        });


    });
```

The types i'm getting now are the populated types from the cars.
Now i want to swap the content of the `car.type` to this result and generate my own populated response.

Anyone any clue how to do this? It's probably pretty easy since i have the `type_id` in both. Just need to map the data from one to the other.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mongoose 4 you can populate documents across multiple levels.

Maybe this post will help you.
[mongoose - populate sub-schema sub-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762588/mongoose-populate-sub-schema-sub-array/44099970#44099970)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this problem. Apparently there is a plugin for mongoose (deep-populate) that allows you to populate 2nd grade child references

Answer (score 0):

Send value of car type as parameter or get it inside request in a variable **value**.

After that you can do it like this:

```
 Order.findOneAndUpdate({customer: customer.slug}, {$set: {car.type: value}}, function (err, customer) {
       if (err) {
           return res.status(500).json({
               title: 'An error occured',
               error: err
           });
       }
    res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Success',
            obj: customer
        });
});
```